# Cannot render correctly using conditionals in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

is there a correct manner to render in React using conditionals that I haven't figured out? I've spent some time with this and can't get why it only renders the 'Standard' . 
Each one of the **Standard, Filled, Premium** components are simple rendering some HTML...
Here's what I've coded.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Standard from "./Standard";
import Filled from "./Filled";
import Premium from "./Premium";

class Plans extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedplan: ""
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick = e => this.setState({ selectedplan: e.target.name });

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }
  render() {
    var plan = this.state.selectedplan;
    let content;
    if (plan === "standard") {
      content = <Standard />;
    } else if (plan === "filled") {
      content = "Testing... worked.?";
    } else if (plan === "premium") {
      content = <Premium />;
    } else {
      content = (
        <div className="lead text-center">Select a plan to view more</div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card card-info text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3 onClick={this.onClick} name="standard">
              Standard
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3 name="filled" onClick={this.onClick}>
              Feature-Filled
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card card-info text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3 name="premium" onClick={this.onClick}>
              Super Premium
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="container text-center justify-content-center">
          {content}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Plans.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Plans);
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `() => this.setState({ selectedplan: "standard" })` instead of `(plan = "standard")`, then it will at least rerender.

Comment: You need mange it with state. You are dealing with local variable so every time you click nothing will happen meaning your component re render. So you need keep variable in state and on every click do setState so that you will see desired content

Comment: Thank you ! I had it previously and it rendered standard even when I clicked on the other titles... perhaps I'll edit the code block above to this to check for help

Comment: Is your problem solved, or are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Still not working! :/

Comment: @PedroSilveira what problems are occuring now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction.

```js
class Plans extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedplan: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    let { selectedplan } = this.state,
      content;

    if (selectedplan === "standard") {
      content = <div>Standard</div>;
    } else if (selectedplan === "filled") {
      content = <div>Filled</div>;
    } else if (selectedplan === "premium") {
      content = <div>Premium</div>;
    } else {
      content = (
        <div className="lead text-center">Select an option to view more</div>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card card-info text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3
              onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedplan: "standard" })}
              name="standard"
            >
              Standard
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3
              name="filled"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedplan: "filled" })}
            >
              Feature-Filled
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div
            className="col-sm-4 card card-info text-center justify-content-center"
            style={{ margin: "auto" }}
          >
            <h3
              name="premium"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedplan: "premium" })}
            >
              Super Premium
            </h3>
            <ul>
              <li />
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div className="container text-center justify-content-center">
          {content}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Plans />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id='root'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could highlight the aspect of the code you changed

Comment: Thanks to everyone and @YakovKiszner it seems to work finely. I forgot about the destructuring.

Comment: I don't understand, your code above should work too.